# A class attribute type of List which is not modifiable by accessor

Tags: java, getter-setter, accessor, mutators

Consider the following class:

```
class Foo
{
  private List<Integer> all;
  private Set<Integer> distinct;
  public List<Integer> getAll()
  {
    return all;
  }
  public void add(Integer i)
  {
    all.add(i);
    distinct.add(i);
  }
}
```

I don't want `bar` to be modified like so:

```
foo.getAll().add(3);
```

instead, I want to force my own `add()` procedure.
Is there a way to do this?

Comment: What is bar? This code would throw a compilation error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can make `getAll()` returning an [unmodifiable list](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#unmodifiableList%28java.util.List%29). You can think it like if it was returning a view, so the list will only be in read-only mode.

Any calls that will try modify the list returned will throw an `UnsupportedOperationException`.

```
public List<Integer> getAll(){
    return Collections.unmodifiableList(all);
}
```